# REGEXP_SUBSTR where in condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this data in a table

```
procedure1/loc1/p1
proc2/loc1/p2/c1
proc1/loc2/p2/c2
procedure3/loc1/p1
procedure4/loc3/p1
```

I want a query to select specific proc, like proc1 and procedure4 , `like` wouldnt work so 
the ouptput should be like this

```
proc1/loc2/p2/c2 
procedure4/loc3/p1
```

I tried to use REGEXP_SUBSTR, but how include the list of the procedure that i want ?

```
--this is wrong 
select *  from tab1 where  REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1,
'[^/]+', 1, 1) in ('proc1','procedure4')
```

Comment: Change 'PROC1' to 'proc1'. and your query should work.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz typo mistake , its lower letter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could check, if the length returned by `REGEXP_SUBSTR` is greater than `0`

```
select *
from (select 'procedure1/loc1/p1' a from dual union
      select 'proc2/loc1/p2/c1' from dual union
      select 'proc1/loc2/p2/c2' from dual union
      select 'procedure3/loc1/p1' from dual union
      select 'procedure4/loc3/p1' from dual) t
where length(regexp_substr(t.a, 'procedure4|proc1')) > 0
```

alternativly you could use `REGEXP_LIKE`, which does simply return a `boolean` and in my oppinion would fit better here.

```
select *
from (select 'procedure1/loc1/p1' a from dual union
      select 'proc2/loc1/p2/c1' from dual union
      select 'proc1/loc2/p2/c2' from dual union
      select 'procedure3/loc1/p1' from dual union
      select 'procedure4/loc3/p1' from dual) t
where regexp_like(t.a, 'procedure4|proc1')
```

O/P

```
proc1/loc2/p2/c2
procedure4/loc3/p1
```

if you would want to get the values from a table you could generate the regex dynamicly with the `listagg` function provided by oracle. What happens now is, that each possible value, that could occure is getting concatinated with an `|`, which does represent an `or` in regex. Due to this you  you're not in need for an `in`, because your regex will have each possible value seperated by an `or`

```
select *
from (select 'procedure1/loc1/p1' a from dual union
      select 'proc2/loc1/p2/c1' from dual union
      select 'proc1/loc2/p2/c2' from dual union
      select 'procedure3/loc1/p1' from dual union
      select 'procedure4/loc3/p1' from dual) t
where regexp_like(t.a, (select listagg(regexp.b, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY regexp.b) regex
                        from   (select 'procedure4' b from dual union
                                select 'proc1'        from dual) regexp))
```

O/P of the subquery used for the regex would be `proc1|procedure4`, which would be the regexp needed as seen in the previous example

Comment: the data in my case is another table , the `where in` would work ?

Comment: @Moudiz i did edit the question so it does generate the regex dynamicly

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use regular expressions to do that. You just could use ordinary `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` to get the substring from the beginning to the first `/`:

```
WITH your_table AS ( 
  SELECT 'procedure1/loc1/p1' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'proc2/loc1/p2/c1' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'proc1/loc2/p2/c2' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'procedure3/loc1/p1' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'procedure4/loc3/p1' procedure_name FROM dual
)
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE SUBSTR(procedure_name,1,INSTR(procedure_name,'/')-1) IN ('proc1','procedure4');
```

However, if you want to learn to use regular expressions in Oracle. You could use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` like this:

```
WITH your_table AS ( 
  SELECT 'procedure1/loc1/p1' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'proc2/loc1/p2/c1' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'proc1/loc2/p2/c2' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'procedure3/loc1/p1' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'procedure4/loc3/p1' procedure_name FROM dual
)
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(procedure_name,'^(.+?)/',1,1,'i',1) IN ('proc1','procedure4');
```

The last parameter tells Oracle to return the match for the pattern between ().

As already mentioned, you also could use `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
WITH your_table AS ( 
  SELECT 'procedure1/loc1/p1' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'proc2/loc1/p2/c1' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'proc1/loc2/p2/c2' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'procedure3/loc1/p1' procedure_name FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'procedure4/loc3/p1' procedure_name FROM dual
)
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(procedure_name,'^(proc1|procedure4)/');
```

Answer (score 2):

If the procedures you are interesetd in are in a different table, one way could be the following:

**Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (col) AS
    (SELECT 'procedure1/loc1/p1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'proc2/loc1/p2/c1'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'proc1/loc2/p2/c2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'procedure3/loc1/p1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'procedure4/loc3/p1' FROM DUAL
    )


CREATE TABLE procedures (name) AS
    (SELECT 'proc1'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'procedure4' FROM DUAL
    )
```

You can try this, with no need for regular expressions:

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
    INNER JOIN procedures
      ON (INSTR(col, name) != 0)
```